# strptime() cannot read time format despite being theoretically correct

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to parse a datetime object from a cell in MS excel, I have successfully done this with alternative time formats but `strptime()` seems to have difficulty with this one format.

I've printed the cell value, which is correct, I have another operation which processes a similar field but without the time and tz information which works.

Code snippet:

```
report_date = datetime.strptime(gs_df_vars.iloc[2, 1], '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y') # Works just fine
print(report_date)
print(gs_df_vars.iloc[3, 1])
run_date = datetime.strptime(gs_df_vars.iloc[3, 1], '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z').strftime('%d/%m/%Y') # Does not work just fine at all
```

raises

```
ValueError: time data 'Jun 14, 2019 02:42 AM EDT' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z'
```

where `gs_df_vars.iloc[3, 1] == 'Jun 14, 2019 02:42 AM EDT'`

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I expect it to just work... Perhaps `strptime()` can't deal with EDT timezone?

Comment: As far as I know, python has issues with parsing timezones

Comment: There are very few timezone names that `strptime()` can reliably understand. See [this Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue22377).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably won't work because those abbreviations aren't unique. You might wind up just having to manually handle it yourself if you're working with a known set of inputs. See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ for more info

If you can pass a dict of timezone abbreviation and corresponding dict. It should work.

```
from dateutil import tz
from dateutil.parser import parse

ET = tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
CT = tz.gettz('US/Central')
MT = tz.gettz('US/Mountain')
PT = tz.gettz('US/Pacific')

us_tzinfos = {'CST': CT, 'CDT': CT,
              'EST': ET, 'EDT': ET,
              'MST': MT, 'MDT': MT,
              'PST': PT, 'PDT': PT}

dt_est = parse('2014-01-02 04:00:00 EST', tzinfos=us_tzinfos)
dt_pst = parse('2016-03-11 16:00:00 PST', tzinfos=us_tzinfos)
```